# testing around Devise and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I'm trying to add tests to my project.
do you know of any guides on adding tests to projects with Devise and OmniAuth ?
Do you know any open source with these kinds of tests ?

Answer (score 0):

The github wiki for devise has a couple pages on testing. I've found them to be helpful guides.

Testing with Cucumber: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Cucumber
Testing with RSpec: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Comment: I'm looking for an open source project where I can learn from the tests. do you know any ?